# jQuery, if "a" tag has class or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get a popup open when I'm pressing a a tag with class: "disable".

This is what i have right now: When I'm clicking on "**tab-link**" that has class "**disable**" I get an alert saying "**yes**",

but when I'm clicking on "**tab-link**"  that do not have disable i still get a message saying "**Yes**".

```js
$(".tab-link").click(function() {
  if ($(".tab-link").hasClass("disable")) {
    alert("Yes");
  } else if (!$(".tab-link").hasClass("disable")) {
    alert("No");
  }
});
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">today</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">today</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">today</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-games" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">rocket_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">rocket_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Games</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-todo" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Todo</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-download" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">download_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">download_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Download</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-search" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">search</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">search</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">search</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Search</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".tab-link")` always points to the first matched element in the document.

Try with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to refer the currently clicked element like the following way:

```
$(".tab-link").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disable")) {
    alert("Yes");
  } else{
    alert("No");
  }
});
```

```js
$(".tab-link").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disable")) {
    alert("Yes");
  } else{
    alert("No");
  }
});

function loadFirebase(){}
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">today</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">today</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">today</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-games" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">rocket_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">rocket_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Games</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-todo" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Todo</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-download" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">download_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">download_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Download</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-search" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">search</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">search</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">search</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Search</span>
</a>
```

Comment: That works on the PC but on the webapp on my phone i got No on every click